# Why doesn't the "text-justify: align" method for evenly spaced menus work?

Tags: html, css, text-align

Patrick Kunka's blog post [Text-align: Justify and RWD](http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/) describes a clean method of evenly spacing elements.

It worked for me most of the time, but sometimes it didn't -- and I couldn't understand why. But finally I stumbled on an explanation, and decided to create this self-answer post.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<ul id="Grid">
        <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li class="break"></li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS (taken directly from the blog post, except I've added borders and background to make elements visible, and also added a reset for lists):

```
#Grid{
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 0.1px; /*hide whitespace between elements*/
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#Grid li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 23%;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    border-right: 3px green solid;
}

#Grid .break{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    ...
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exizt/L6svf/1/)

**The `text-align` property has no effect. Why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements in the markup **must have whitespace (spaces or newlines) between them.**

```
<ul id="Grid">
    <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> <li class="break"></li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exizt/5SQGx/)

---

I've encountered this problem mostly with PHP-generated markup, which lacks the usual formatting. For example, this often happens when populating lists with `foreach`.

Comment: If you want 0 font-size, use 0. `0.1px` is invalid and browsers will still respect their min font size setting. With 0, it's 0.

Comment: For those who may be struggling with this: try adding &nbsp; after each LI. It's the only thing that worked for me on my current project.

Comment: @Rudie 0.1px is an IE9 hack, apparently.

Comment: But it doesn't work in Chrome... Not a very good IE9 hack. I see font size 18, because that's my minimum. If it's 0, I see 0.

Comment: `font-size: 0px` doesn't work for me in IE9. So perhaps both lines are in order?